# 403 "Request had insufficient authentication scopes" when creating drafts in Google API with Python

Tags: python-2.7, gmail-api

I am working with the google api for the first time, and am new to coding in general, and have a question that I'm sure is very simple, but I cannot find the answer to. When I run the following code -

```
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
labels = results.get('labels', [])

if not labels:
    print('No labels found.')
else:
    print('Labels:')
    for label in labels:
        print(label['name'])


message_body = "This is the message"

message = {'message': message_body}

draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId='me', body=message).execute()
```

I am successfully able to list the labels in my gmail account, but the request to create a draft kicks back an error message "Request had insufficient authentication request". I found that creating drafts requires one of the following scopes:

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose

but for the life of me, I cannot figure out what exactly that means or how to make that happen, though I've done my best to find this somewhere.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably have a global variable `SCOPES` in you code with the value of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly` if you are following the Quickstart. These scopes are used when your users are redirected to Google in order to give you an `access_token` so you can read the contents of your user's gmail account.

In order to send drafts etc. you need one of the scopes you mentioned, e.g. `https://mail.google.com/`. Change your value of `SCOPES` to this string, and remove your credentials located at `~/.credentials/gmail-python-quickstart.json` as outlined by [the Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) in order to get new credentials that can do more than just read content.

Comment: That does indeed answer the question I was asking, so thank you. However, now I am receiving the error "httplib2.CertificateHostnameMismatch: Server presented certificate that does not match host gmail.modify.googleapis.com". It looks like other people have had this error as well, with unclear solutions. Do you have any insight?

Comment: @JamesL Glad it worked! I have no idea what to do about this new error you are getting, sorry. Very peculiar.

Comment: It turns out that I changed some other stuff when trying to fix my first problem, and when I changed it back it fixed the error. Now I'm getting an error "Invalid value at 'draft.message', which is a different problem entirely, and something that I should be able to figure out. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @JamesL Make sure you format your message like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965493/error-400-when-sending-a-message-using-python/38971497#38971497). If you try the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create#try-it) you can see that you need to format the request body like `{ "message": { "raw": "Rdjbf..."} }`

Answer (score 6):

I also found that in your working directory, you need to delete the `token.pickle` file, and then replace the `SCOPES` variable with one of [these](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) depending on your purposes. So, for example, if you're trying to send an email, use

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']
```

Comment: Thanks for linking to the scopes page. (It would be `token.json` these days.)

Answer (score 0):

example for the quickstart code with Ruby using *gem google/apis/gmail_v1* (scope *readonly* seems to be mandatory but additional scopes can be added):

```
SCOPE = Google::Apis::GmailV1::AUTH_GMAIL_READONLY, Google::Apis::GmailV1::AUTH_GMAIL_COMPOSE
```

Remove the tokenfile (token.yaml) before running quickstart.rb and make sure you are in the directory where it is located.
When you go to the link which is generated, you will be asked to approve access for each scope seperately.

In case there are errors with the scope after generating the token (eg *scope can not contain space*), try the following syntax in your code

```
  SCOPE ||= [Google::Apis::GmailV1::AUTH_GMAIL_READONLY, Google::Apis::GmailV1::AUTH_GMAIL_COMPOSE]
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the credentials again and my error got resolved..